# Extend Sales Order Grid to show Printed Yes/No

Tags: php, grid, invoice, sales, print

I'm trying to add a new column to the sales order grid that shows whether an order has previously had its invoice printed out - I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find a solution.

We use custom grids at the moment and have several custom columns

TIA

Answer (score 0):

That can be a bit difficult to track. How are you printing invoices? How do you track whether your customer print an invoice you send attached in an email?

Let say you have a way to track this, I would create a custom order attribute to flag orders and show it in a custom column in grid, look at this for example: `Mage_Sales_Controller_Abstract::printAction()` to a place where set the attribute to true.

You can have your custom controller to handle your attribute flag and then redirect to `Mage_Sales_Controller_Abstract::printAction()`

For more examples on printActions look in admin controllers at:
`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/`

If you are using print functionality from backend then you can add the flag attribute and set the attribute by listening one of the events **controller post/pre dispatch**. Then show attribute in grid.

This is a good resource on how to [add custom attributes to orders](https://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/)

Comment: Hey! thanks for the answer - its actually from the backend only - due to several people using the backend at once we wanted to make sure no one was crossing each others paths

Comment: Hi, I have updated answer, check last paragraph. Hope this help.

Comment: Are there any created solutions I can implement? Only been working with Magento for 6 months and still quite new to it - willing to pay

Comment: Edited again :) if you think I have helped please accept the answer. If still feels like don't want to do the work, feel free to get in touch ;)